# How to find two numbers where a restriction is applied

Tags: prolog

Let's say that I want to find two numbers where the sum of these are 8, are from 1-9 and must be different(it is obvious that these numbers are (7,1),(6,2),etc).So I wrote.

```
dif_list([H|T]):- \+ member(H,T),dif_list(T).
dif_list([]).

check1_9([H|T]):-H>=1,H=<9,check1_9(T).
check1_9([]).

find_number([A,B],N) :- N =:= A+B,dif_list([A,B]),check1_9([A,B]).
```

Afterwards I will ask prolog

```
 ?-find_number([A,B],8).
 ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

My goal is that prolog will print for me the results.For example:

```
?-find_number([A,B],8).
  A = 7,
  B = 1 ;
  A = 6,
  B = 2 ;
  ...
```

Comment: You already accepted an answer before your UPDATE1. It's very bad form here to pose a question, get legitimate answers to that question, and then change or enhance the question, using those answers, thus then making the previously given answers incomplete or invalid. If you have more to ask, please post a new question. I'm voting to close this question on the basis of it not being clear what you're asking since it is changing after answers are already given.

Comment: I second this: Please restore this question, for which valid answers have been given that may be useful for others too, and file a new question for the new issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this kind of problem in Prolog is to use the CLP(FD) library:

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

sum_of(A, B, Sum) :-
    A #> 0,
    B #> 0,
    A + B #= Sum.

?- sum_of(A, B, 8), label([A, B]).
A = 1,
B = 7 ;
A = 2,
B = 6 ;
A = 3,
B = 5 ;
A = B, B = 4 ;
A = 5,
B = 3 ;
A = 6,
B = 2 ;
A = 7,
B = 1.

?-
```

If you want the addends to be unique, you can further constrain it:

```
sum_of(A, B, Sum) :-
    A #> 0,
    B #>= A,
    A + B #= Sum.
```

There's really no need to use a list to manage the variables `A` and `B`, but you can if you wish: `sum_of([A,B], Sum)`.

Answer (score -1):

Prolog is not that declarative: there are indeed *answer set programming* (ASP) or *constraint logic programming* (clp) languages where you can simply define a set of constraints and a finite domain solver aims to solve it (but these will take considerable time).

I would suggest that you define your program as follows:

```
find_number(A,B,N) :-
    member(A,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
    member(B,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
    N is A+B,
    A \= B.
```

Here `member/2` will *instantiate* `A` and `B` to values that are provided by the list, so `1..9`, next you use `is/2` to calculate the sum and verify that the sum is equal to `N`. You can only call `N is A+B` if `A` and `B` are given a proper value. Finally we say `A \= B` (`A` is not equal to `B`).

When you run this predicate, it produces:

```
?- find_number(A,B,8).
A = 1,
B = 7 ;
A = 2,
B = 6 ;
A = 3,
B = 5 ;
A = 5,
B = 3 ;
A = 6,
B = 2 ;
A = 7,
B = 1 ;
false.
```

You can however also query with `A` and `B` already filled in, or one of them filled in, or where the sum is left open. So:

```
?- find_number(A,2,8).
A = 6 ;
false.
```

or:

```
?- find_number(A,2,N).
A = 1,
N = 3 ;
A = 3,
N = 5 ;
A = 4,
N = 6 ;
A = 5,
N = 7 ;
A = 6,
N = 8 ;
A = 7,
N = 9 ;
A = 8,
N = 10 ;
A = 9,
N = 11 ;
false.
```

Comment: Prolog has the CLP(FD) library, so in Prolog you can do declarative arithmetic.

Comment: @lurker: yeah I know that (I worked with it already), which turns Prolog a bit into a constraint logic programming solver. I only meant that by default, Prolog is not a constraint logic programming solver.

Comment: Not sure I totally agree. I guess it depends upon what you mean "by default". GNU Prolog allows constraint logic programming "by default" (without the explicit inclusion of additional libraries). Although SWI requires you to explicitly include the library, it requires other library inclusions as well for what I would consider more basic capabilities. It's considered a mainstream part of Prolog.

Comment: @lurker: well I agree that it can be implemented,etc. What I mean is that there are languages like IDP (KU Leuven) where one simply write constraints, regardless of the order one likes, etc. it works. It does not ship with "constraint programming constraints" and "normal constraints". Of course the downside is the computational complexity.